# System of Multiplicative Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How would I analyze and solve this system of differential equations.
$$
x'(t)= sx^{1/2}(t)y^{1/6}(t)z^{1/3}(t)\qquad y'(t)= cx^{2/3}(t)z^{1/3}(t)\qquad z'(t)= nz(t)
$$

Comment: They are constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: I assume $s,c,n$ to be constants.

From the last equation, you obtain $z(t)=z(0)\exp(n t)$ (hence $z(t)$ is know from now onwards).

Then

$$y'/x'=\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{cx^{2/3}z^{1/3}}{sx^{1/2}y^{1/6}z^{1/3}}=\dfrac{c}{s}\dfrac{x^{1/6}}{y^{1/6}}$$

$$y^{1/6}dy=\dfrac{c}{s}x^{1/6}dx \implies \dfrac{7}{6}y^{7/6}=\dfrac{7}{6}\dfrac{c}{s}x^{7/6}+\dfrac{7}{6}k \implies y(x)=\left[k+\dfrac{c}{s}x^{7/6} \right]^{6/7}$$

Substitute this into the first equation

$$x'=sx^{1/2}\left[\left[k+\dfrac{c}{s}x^{7/6} \right]^{6/7} \right]^{1/6}\left[ z(0)\exp(n t)\right]^{1/3}$$

$$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=sx^{1/2}\left[k+\dfrac{c}{s}x^{7/6} \right]^{1/7} \left[ z(0)\exp(n t)\right]^{1/3}.$$

Note, that the last equation is separable. The solution of this differential equation is now only a problem of integration. I don't see a method to write the solution in a closed form. But if you are able to determine $x(t)$ then $y(t)$ is given by

$$y(t)=y(x(t))=\left[k+\dfrac{c}{s}x(t)^{7/6} \right]^{6/7}$$